# Two resource IDs for controls?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a strange case that (I think) I need two resource IDs for my controls.

I have a static control that I subclassed to a bitmap button. I have three LEDs (also static controls with a bitmap) and when I press the button the next LED should light up. These three LEDs should be associated with the button in some way. I was thinking of giving them the same resource ID as the button, but then I need another ID for the LEDs (`LED1`, `LED2`, `LED3`), which gives the LEDs a value (1, 2, 3). As far as I know you can only have one resource ID for a control.

- Making the button the parent window
  of the LEDs is not an option because
  I want only the button to be
  clickable, not the LEDs.
- Note that I
  also need to have the possibility to
  have 1 or 2 LEDs for a button.

How to do this?

Comment: Do you mean I have to draw a new LED each time I click the button? But then after so many clicks on the button I have a lot of controls. Or is this possible without actually making a control for the bitmap?

Comment: Draw the LED == not making a control.

Comment: Why cant you just use different IDs here? It's not clear why you're having a problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have fixed this. I have drawn the bitmaps directly to screen. I didn't think of that at first...